# How to run unity in headless mode on linux?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to run unity simulation without rendering the graphics at all on linux. Can someone who did it provide steps in detail to do so? I can across a lot of resources online for my problem but none worked for me.

Comment: *"I can across a lot of resources online for my problem but none worked for me."* It would be benefitial to cite those resources and explain why they didn't work for you, as otherwise people might answer with the very solutions you have already unsuccessfully tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `batchmode` and `nographics` command line arguements to do this:

```
/opt/Unity/Editor/Unity -batchmode -nographics -logFile
```

Note that you must replace `/opt/Unity/Editor/Unity` with the part of the Unity Editor or the build you want to run in a headless mode. If you run into issues, there is more detailed post about the issues and their fixes on [this](https://medium.com/@h0lycattle/running-unity3d-in-a-virtualized-headless-ubuntu-environment-1adf95c05994) post.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it worked. Do you have any idea if we can still capture screenshots and save them while working in no graphics mode ?

Comment: I don't think you can because nographics mode means that the graphics stuff are not initialized. I suggest you use remove nographics argument and see what happens. I've also seen post before on this about about a person who tried to capture screenshot but that didn't work so that may not work.

Comment: Note that if your first question has been answered, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer to mark it as solved. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for how to do that